# Blank workbook is output with WriteOnlyCell and example from documentation

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl 2.2.6 from the bitbucket repository. I tried the simple example from the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html#optimized-writer)

This however produces a blank workbook with a single sheet approproately named "MyTestSheet" . but values in any cell.

What am I missing to get write to a cell to work.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook(optimized_write = True)
ws = wb.create_sheet(title="MyTestSheet")
from openpyxl.writer.dump_worksheet import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl.comments import Comment
from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font
cell = WriteOnlyCell(ws, value="hello world")
cell.font = Font(name='Courrier', size=36)
cell.comment = Comment(text="A comment", author="Author's Name")
wb.save("testwr_so.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the cell to the worksheet:

`ws.append([cell]) # you must always append a sequence`